# Oracle 10g (Win 64-bit) installation on Windows 7 64 bit fails

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i, oracle-apex

I have constantly failed to install Oracle 10 g on my windows 7. I selected the right download for my operating system but the installer brings a terminal which asks me to press enter to exit while showing the error that `Operating system version 6.1 is not supported -- Failed`

I tried a hack found here: http://windows7bugs.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/install-oracle-10g-onward-database-developer-on-windows-7/ but still failed.
 The hack required me to alter the `?PATH\database\stage\prereq\db\refhost.xml` as well as the `?PATH\database\stage\prereq\db_prereqs\db\refhost.xml` files to add the lines under *CERTIFIED_SYSTEMS* like this:

```
<OPERATING_SYSTEM>
  <VERSION VALUE="6.1"/>
</OPERATING_SYSTEM>
```

Having done all this and many other hacks i have failed. I tried getting `Windows XP Mode for windows 7` found here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx
to help create an XP virtual environment so that Oracle can install, but i failed to get it since am a `Windows 7 Home Premium , 64 bit` user. 
**Anyone running windows 7 64 bit Home Premium or any other windows 7, who has probably faced the same problem, and has managed to install Oracle, do explain how you did it, please?** thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle is an Enterprise software tool, and as such is only supported on Windows Professional operating systems.  I agree that this is a bit provoking, especially when the OTN Download License appears to encourage self-learning but that's the way it is.

Have you considered using a virtual image instead?  Install Oracle's Virtual Box on your PC and then you can run the OTN Developer Day VM.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html).